# StackLayout with Labels acting weird

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

So I'm coding a Hang Man game. I've done it with WPF already and now trying with Xamarin. In WPF, I figured out a smart way to show the correct guessed letters:

[image: SPLetters: StackLayout with Labels in it (Each label displays one letter from the word to guess | triedLetter: the guessed letter)]

So I go through every Label in this `StackLayout` and I look if the label's content is equal to the `triedLetter`. If so, I set the label to visible.

Btw. the method to give each label a letter from the word:
[image: letters: Char[] with each letter of the word | lblLetter1: each label's name]

On Xamarin, this happens:

```
wordToGuess = test
every Label: ----
triedLetter: t -> StackLayout: Tt--
triedLetter: s -> StackLayout: Tst-
triedLetter: e -> StackLayout: Test
```

On my wpf project it looked like this:

```
wordToGuess = test
every label: ----
triedLetter: t -> StackLayout: T--t
triedLetter: s -> StackLayout: T-st
triedLetter: e -> StackLayout: Test
```

Any idea why? Seems like `StackLayout`s are acting different from `StackPanel`s on WPF.

And yes, I know there are some questions about the same topic, but they're doing it differently. And before I take someone else's idea, I like to solve my way instead.

Comment: The visibility of a stack layout will change others above/below (vertical) or that which is left/right (horizontal) because they do exactly that, stack. Maybe use opacity instead to solve your problem.

Comment: First, please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Second, using a Grid would probably work better fhan a StackLayout for your UI

Comment: @Skin But why does Visibility work on WPF but not on Xamarin??

Comment: I'm not a WPF man so can't answer that one, sorry!

Comment: Is there a way to make text underlining always visible? I want the underlining to be always visible, but the letters invisible. Just for the word length indicator (Label TextDecoration)

Comment: `On Xamarin, this happens:ordToGuess = test every label: ---- triedLetter: t -> StackLayout: T--t triedLetter: s -> StackLayout: T-st triedLetter: e -> StackLayout: Test`   Sorry, I don't quite follow your logic. What features do you want to implement? And what exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Oh sry, the question is solved. The opacity worked. Do I have to credit him in any way or mark the question as solved? I'm new here

Comment: Congrats.  You can add an answer  here and mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems.  Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve :
Instead of `label.IsVisible = true/false`, I used `label.Opacity = 0/100`
Thanks to Skin for the solution !